# Google Colab - writing out a .csv but overwriting file?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm hoping this is a straightforwardly simple thing to do, but I can't find a solution for. I'm using Google Colab to process some data on a daily basis that I then read into another program. I use:

```
files.download('today_out.csv')
```

It outputs to my `windows/user/downloads` directory. I would like, if possible, to be able to overwrite this file - but the Windows file system end up creating a `today_out.csv(1)` and I'd rather just overwrite the existing `today_out.csv`. Is there a way to do this in Colab?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read local files on your computer from Colab. But you can create a local python script and run it before running Colab.

Before downloading the file, you can check if the file exists and delete it.

```
try:
    os.remove("file.csv")
except OSError:
    pass
```